# Is it possible to get exact location(possition) on detecting object with bounding box in android studio with arcore

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, arcore

I am developing an Arcore android app which detect  computer keyboards(also train with bounding box on arrow key) and arrow keys.I want to do is when it detect arrow key, put a 3d object on arrow key(exactly on arrow key) I tried to get bounding box values and set it to node "setLocalPosition" .but doesn't work. I want to know is it possible to it using android studio with arcore  and if it is ,please give me some ideas .